# Node.js: Conditional content depending on user authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, pug, passport.js

I have this method in my controller to check if a user is logged in. It uses passport.js and works fine.

```
exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
    return;
  }
```

In one of my views I want to show certain content to the user only if he is logged in. The view is part of the header of the page. If the user is logged out he is presented with the two buttons "register" and "log in".
If he is logged in, he should be presented with "account" (to manage his account) and "log out".

I use pug and tried the following. It obivously doesn't work as the function isn't defined in the pug file. Also I am not sure if this is the right approach.

```
if !isAuthenticated()
  a(href="/register") Register
  a(href="/login") Log in
if isAuthenticated()
  a(href="/account") Account
  a(href="/logout") Log out
```

Comment: Then what do you want ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I updated the post to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to pass the value of isAuthenticated to your view.

I don't usually use pug myself, but it looks like you need to do the following to pass variables:

```
var isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
pug.renderFile('template.pug', {
  authenticated: isAuthenticated
})
```

and then use authenticated in your pug file.

Comment: I don't know if this solution would make sense. The pug code from my code above is used in all of my pug templates, which are 20++ at this point already.
If I understand correctly i would have to add your code every single time I render a view.

Comment: @koedev you can define a common middlware that is used by all your routes and put this code in that middleware. So you don't need to write it separately for each page.

Comment: Yeah but this is what i meant. I would have to put the middleware in there 20++ x times vs only once if i can do it in the pug